# Boto3: insert data into dynamodb table

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a DynamoDB table called `events` and I want to `put` the data into the table.

My dynamodb table structure is given below

```
{
 "partition_key": "user_id1111",
 "sort_key": "version_1",
 "attributes": {
  "events": [
   {
    "t": "1614712316",  
    "a": "product_view",   
    "i": "1275"
   },
   ...
   ...
   ...
  ]
 }
}
```

I have 2 entries of data:

```
entry1 = {
     "t": 1607208938861,
     "a": "product_add",
     "i": "142320"
}
```

```
entry2 = 
    {
      "M": {
       "t": {
        "N": "1607208938862"
       },
       "a": {
        "S": "product_purchase"
       },
       "i": {
        "S": "142318"
       }
      }
     }
```

I want to insert there two entries into the dynamodb table.

I know we can use `BOTO3-Dynamodb-resource` to insert `entry1` into the table

I know we can use `BOTO3-Dynamodb-client` to insert `entry2` into the table

**NOTE:**

`entry1` ==> the data will always be in the format similar to `dynamodb resource`

`entry2` ==> the data will always be in the format similar to `dynamodb client`

**GOAL:**

using single `boto3-resource` method(`put-item`), I want to insert these two records into dynamodb table.

**MY FINAL OUTPUT IN THE DYNAMODB TABLE WILL BE SIMILAR TO BELOW**

```
{
 "partition_key": "user_id1111",
 "sort_key": "version_1",
 "attributes": {
  "events": [
     {
     "t": 1607208938861,
     "a": "product_add",
     "i": "142320"
     },
     {
     "t": 1607208938862,
     "a": "product_purchase",
     "i": "142318"
     },

   
  ]
 }
}
```

**Can anyone suggest a solution for this?**

Comment: `entry2` uses the internal DynamoDB data format, while `entry1` is the purely python version, which the resource API transforms to the DynamoDB data format under the hood. The solution is easy: if you want to use the resource API, you need to transform `entry2` into a format the resource API understands. Please show us what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: basically I used this python library: https://pypi.org/project/dynamodb-json/  to convert `dynamodb-json` format into python version and then I used BOTO3-DYNAMODB-resource to put the data into dynamodb. It solves my problem

Comment: You can also add that as an answer to this question and accept it - that's okay here. That way users can see the question is solved on first glance. Solutions in the comments bypass the usual quality control measures ;-)

Comment: ok, i will add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I found a python library called `dynamodb-json`: https://pypi.org/project/dynamodb-json/

this library helps us to convert `dynamodb-json` format into `python representation`. then, we can directly use boto3-dynamodb-resource to put python representation of an entry into dynamodb.

```
import boto3
import json
from dynamodb_json import json_util as dbjson


dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
dbtable = dynamodb.Table('events')


entry1 = json.dumps({
     "t": 1607208938861,
     "a": "product_add",
     "i": "142320"
})

entry2 = 
    {
      "M": {
       "t": {
        "N": "1607208938862"
       },
       "a": {
        "S": "product_purchase"
       },
       "i": {
        "S": "142318"
       }
      }
     }


# convert entry2 into python representation
obj = json.dumps(dbjson.loads(entry2))

in_list = []
in_list.append(json.loads(entry1))
in_list.append(json.loads(obj))

response = dbtable.put_item(
           Item={
              "cache_key": "user_id1111",
              "sort_key": "version_1",
              "attributes": {"events":in_list},
     }
        )
```

The above code solves my problem.